# ASP.NET custom MembershipProvider and shared DbContexts

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-membership

I have created a custom MembershipProvider in an MVC web appliocation. My GetUser function returns an instance of my own custom Employee class which inherits from the standard MembershipUser. This allows me to supply additional details for the each user such as various employee details.

```
    public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {   
        return new ModelRepository().GetModels<Employee>().Where(e => e.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

The problem I'm having, the membership provider spawns a new instance of my repository class (which creates a new DbContext) to retrieve the Employee object. This Employee object is then passed to whatever request/controller action called the Membership api.

```
Employee currentUser = (Employee)Membership.GetUser();
```

That calling request will often want to create a new object in memory, lets say a new SicknessRecord and assign the user retrieved earlier to that record and then save it to the DB with its **own** model repository. You can probably see where this is going, the framework complains that I'm trying to save an object (the user) with a context that it wasn't initially retrieved with.

My current, rather hackish solution is to just use the ID of the user retrieved from the Membership.GetUser and go and re-retrieve the Employee object from my current model repository.

```
newSickness.Employee = this.modelRepository.GetModelById<Employee>(this.me.Id.Value);
```

I've tried detaching the Employee object but then it loses its lazy loaded properties and I have to remember to try and attach it again to my current repository/context.

I've also read it is good to have your custom membership provider share the same context that the current request would be using. Any ideas how to achieve this, how do I ensure the membership provider uses the same context as the one spawned when a user executes a controller action?

Answer (score 0):

You can have one separate DbContext instance for each controller.

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private DbContext context = new DbContext();
    private CustomMembershipProvider membershipProvider = new CutomMembershipProvider(this.context);

    ... Actions ....
}
```

As far as I know, one context per controller is good practice.

By the way, if you have several repositories try to use UnitOfWork with Repository pattern.